# MultiTheading in Java having static and non static method

Tags: java, multithreading, static, non-static

I had been trying out different behavior of multi-threading in java. If i am using both synchronized static and non static method in a class.
What i had understood is,

-> if the thread enters into a synchronize method the thread acquire the lock of an object until the execution of method.

-> if the thread enters into a static synchronize method the thread acquire the lock of a class  instead of an object.

The Real confusion part is the output ??.

```
    package com.threadImplementaion.examples;

class MyRunable implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        iterationMethod() ;
        staticIteration();
    }
    public synchronized void iterationMethod() 
    {
        //int count = 0  ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " +  i);
        }
    }
    public  static synchronized  void staticIteration()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +  " static "  +  i);
        }
    }
}
public class MyRunnable 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new MyRunable() ;
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable);
        thread1.start();
        thread1.setName("Thread1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnable) ;
        thread2.start();
        thread2.setName("Thread2") ;
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(runnable); 
        thread3.start();
        thread3.setName("Thread3");
        }


}



Output :
Thread1 : 0
Thread1 : 1
Thread1 : 2
Thread1 : 3
Thread1 : 4
Thread1 static 0
Thread1 static 1
Thread1 static 2
Thread1 static 3
Thread1 static 4
Thread1 static 5
**Thread1 static 6**
Thread3 : 0
Thread3 : 1
Thread3 : 2
Thread3 : 3
Thread3 : 4
Thread2 : 0
Thread2 : 1
Thread1 static 7
Thread2 : 2
Thread1 static 8
Thread2 : 3
Thread1 static 9
Thread2 : 4
Thread2 static 0
Thread2 static 1
Thread2 static 2
Thread2 static 3
Thread2 static 4
Thread2 static 5
Thread2 static 6
Thread2 static 7
Thread2 static 8
Thread2 static 9
Thread3 static 0
Thread3 static 1
Thread3 static 2
Thread3 static 3
Thread3 static 4
Thread3 static 5
Thread3 static 6
Thread3 static 7
Thread3 static 8
Thread3 static 9
```

Comment: What's confusing in the output? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A synchronized `static` method obtains a lock on the `Class` object `X` representing the class in which the method is defined. In this case, the `synchronized` keyword is in principle meant to synchronize between `static` methods only.

Whereas a synchronized instance (non-`static`) method locks the current object `Y` on which the method is called.

Therefore, a synchronized `static` method and a synchronized instance method can still interleave because they lock on two different objects.

Answer (score 1):

`static` methods lock/unlock the class(`MyRunable`) object where as non static methods lock/unock the `MyRunable` objects. And this both are different, I mean to say.

> A synchronized method (§[8.4.3.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6)) automatically performs a lock action
>   when it is invoked; its body is not executed until the lock action has
>   successfully completed.
>
> If the method is an instance method, it locks  the monitor associated
>   with the instance for which it was invoked  (that is, the object that
>   will be known as this during execution of  the body of the method).
>
> If the method is static, it locks the monitor  associated with the
>   Class object that represents the class in which  the method is
>   defined.
>
> If execution of the method's body is ever completed, either normally
>   or abruptly, an unlock action is  automatically performed on that same
>   monitor.

[Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)